Change in magnetic field due to induced EMF
I am currently experimenting with problems using induced EMF. I was dealing with a problem where I had a source of a constant magnetic field, but as I understand it when and EMF is induced it causes an opposing magnetic field. In a situation where we don't have some magical source of magnetic field that opposes all changes caused by the induced EMF would the magnetic field change the total magnetic field, and thus change the EMF induced and so on? if this is the case are most elementary problems just ignoring this? or assuming the source of the magnetic field compensates for this? Sorry if this is confusingly worded, I am struggling to phrase it in an understandable way through text.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you talking about inductance? Which quantifies a systems ability to resist it's own change in emf?

It sounds to me like you are grappling with the difference between opposing and canceling. If you try to change the magnetic field in a region, an EMF will be induced that would (should it be in the vicinity of a conductor) create a magnetic field that opposes the change in the magnetic field. This does not mean the field made by any induced current CANCELS the change! It merely slows the change down (again, only if the EMF can make some nearby charges move).

Let me ask you , when does EMF is generated due to a magnetic field ?
It does happen when the magnetic flux ,$\phi_B= nBA$ , through the conductor changes or the conductor cuts magnetic field lines ( during its motion ).

$n$= number of turns in the loop


$B$= instantaneous magnetic field


$A$= area of the loop

Now there are many ways to change the magnetic flux through a stationary conductor ( let the conductor be a circular loop of one turn in our case ):

By changing the area of the loop.
By changing the magnetic field.
Or by changing the number of turns ( which I am taking constant and equal to $1$ )


I had a source of a constant magnetic field

You are saying that a through a constant magnetic field source , you are going to generate EMF , then we would have to use our $1$st method i.e.  by changing the area .  BUT

would the magnetic field change the total magnetic field, and thus change the EMF induced and so on?

to answer this , I would like to go through the second method i.e. by changing the Magnetic field.

Here , the magnetic field increases, outward to the plane of image , with a constant rate , $c$ ,as shown and the area remains constant, equal to $A$
( with radius $r$  i.e. $A=πr²$ ). And , let the resistance of the loop be $R$.
Then , Magnetic flux through the loop at an instant , $$\phi_B=BA.$$ So, EMF induced in the loop is : $$|E| =\frac{d{\phi_B}}{dt}= A\frac{dB}{dt}=Ac (constant)$$
Then , the corresponding induced ,  constant current would be :$$i=\frac{|E|}{R}= \frac{Ac}{R}$$
Here , we have neglected the increase in the resistance of the coil due to heating .
So , the corresponding opposite Magnetic field ( produced by the induced current ) would have the relation:$$B_i > \frac{\mu_oi}{2r}$$$$B_i > \frac{\mu_oAc/R}{2√{A/π}}$$$$B_i > \frac{\mu_oπc√A}{2R}$$ , which  is a constant also.

magnetic field that opposes all changes caused by the induced EMF would the magnetic field change the total magnetic field, and thus change the EMF induced and so on

Since this opposing field is constant, so the it can't affect "the rate of change" in magnetic field from the source and hence can't change the induced EMF and so not the induced current.
When it doesn't work ?

Initially  , when we would be switching on the source , this opposing magnetic field would be getting generated in the direction opposite to the external ( i.e. it too would have a rate of change in that interval ) , but over time it would become constant and would tend to the above described situation.

If we take into account the change in resistance of the coil due to heating . ( But it is negligible enough , at least for some time in the starting ).


